# What is the difference between passport,jwt and Oauth2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, laravel-passport, laravel-9

I am full confuse seem to be all similar, when to use it all this i can figure out.``

Fully confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **OAuth2** is an authorization framework protocol that uses access tokens: [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)
- **JWT** ([RFC7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)) stands for **Json Web Token**, which is a data format for transmitting claims that can be digitally signed (**JWS** - [RFC7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515)), encrypted (**JWE** - [RFC7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516)) or both. They can be used as access tokens.
- **Passport** is an implementation of **OAuth2** for Laravel that uses **JWT** under the hood ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport)).